# Should the asyncData option be used when using universal mode in nuxt?

Tags: single-page-application, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently working on a project using nuxt.

Then, there is a problem with auth.

Whenever I use middleware to move the page, I take the token out of the cookie and put it in the axios default token.

I have a problem with this flow because I use universal mode.

Because the middleware of the client is run when moving pages, and server's middleware when refreshing, token is stored in the client's axios default header and server's axios default header respectively.

So I cannot bring data from client after refresh.

This is resolved using asyncData, but should all data be brought to asyncData?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new `fetch()` hook from Nuxt > v2.12 is the solution to your problems? Check here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/

Answer (score 0):

You can still access the cookie in your server Middleware without being on the client side. The cookie is actually in your request header.

An middleware would look something like this:

To access the request header you can destruct the nuxt context

```
 export default function({ req }){
    console.log(req.headers.cookie);
 }
```